# Vim travel to pathfile determined in vimrc

Tags: file, vim, shortcut

How do I open a file specified in vimrc, with a key combination?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly clear what you mean, but if you just want a key combination to open a file specified in vimrc, you could do something like this:

```
:nmap ,e :e /path/to/my/file.txt<CR>
```

Pressing `,e` will then open your requested file.